# Java System.out.println Single quotes

Tags: java

What is the output if we write -

```
System.out.println('Hello World');
```

We use single quotes instead of double quotes?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: The output would be to ask you to resolve compilation errors. you can only run a program if there are no compilation issues.

Comment: Lol what amazes me is the number of views this question has got,so many pissed off people coming here to takeout their frustration on a newbie

Answer (score 4):

Single quotes are allowed only for `char` values, for example:

```
char a = 'A';
```

Comment: actually giving an answer is much better than mocking someone....well done

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava when I was 8 years old my teacher used to tell me that there is a mistake in my homework, and **not** pointing out where is it. I thought that it's terrible, but now, every time I see someone who asks a question w/o trying to find out what's wrong, w/o reading the book - just "Guys, I don't understand, help me on that", I understand that she was right. I learnt how to learn - by reading books/tutorials and figuring out my mistakes myself.

Comment: @aga but many times people are so confused that they don't know where to begin with ...

Answer (score 2):

This would be answered by running this very simple program, it's a compile error as single quotes are for characters only

Answer (score 2):

Single quote are allowed for `char`(single letter) not for `String`(multple letter).

```
char ch='A';
String str="ABC"
```

Answer (score 1):

It wont even compile.As you are enclosing a string with single qoute

Answer (score 1):

It will leads to compile time error.

`'` is used for `char s = 'A';`